# Bold italic swashed z does not show up in mtpro2 complete

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, mtpro

I am using the [MathTime Professional 2 fonts](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html) from PCTeX. Unfortunately, my problem is testable only to those who have purchased the *Complete* version. The *Lite* version is available on CTAN, and you may find the package implementation, i.e., the `mtpro2.dtx` file [here on CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/source/latex/mtpro2) as well.

With the `zswash` option, I expect to obtain a swashed `z` in both Math Italic *and* Math Bold Italic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[zswash]{mtpro2}% Complete
\begin{document}
$z$ $\mathbold{z}$ How to fix?\par
\makeatletter
$\mtp@z$ $\mathbold{\mtp@z}$\par
$\mtp@@z$ $\mathbold{\mtp@@z}$\par
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image: zswash]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\mathbold` is declared as a math alphabet and the swash z is obtained by making `z` math active with a definition that reads

> if the current math group is −1, use the swash z (`\mtp@@z`), otherwise use z (`\mtp@z`)

This obviously fails in the scope of `\mathbold`, which uses a specific math group.

Cure: modify the code for the math active `z` to check for the specific math group for bold letters. This requires redefining `\mathbold` with `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`.

Since I don't have the full version of `mtpro2`, I emulated it with the medium weight font; you should substitute `{m}` in the code below with `{b}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite,zswash]{mtpro2} % remove lite in your document

%\DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it} % use this line
% the following line is for testing without the full version, remove it
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}

% with \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet we know the family allocated to \mathbold,
% which is internally known as \symboldletters
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbold}{boldletters}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\z
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
  \ifnum\mathgroup=\m@ne
    \mtp@@z
  \else
    %%% added test
    \ifnum\mathgroup=\symboldletters
      \mtp@@z
    \else
      \mtp@z
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$z+\mathbold{z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `expl3`, where the test is more readable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite,zswash]{mtpro2} % remove lite in your document
\usepackage{expl3}

%\DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it} % use this line
% the following line is for testing without the full version, remove it
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}

% with \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet we know the family allocated to \mathbold,
% which is internally known as \symboldletters
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbold}{boldletters}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mtproii_swashz:
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \mathgroup }
   {
    {-1}{\use:c {mtp@@z}}
    {\symboldletters}{\use:c {mtp@@z}}
   }
   {\use:c {mtp@z}}
 }
\char_set_active_eq:NN z \mtproii_swashz:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$z+\mathbold{z}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Umm, neither method seems to work correctly -- at least not with my vintage of the "full" version of the `mtpro2` package. (I bought my copy about 7 years ago; I have no idea if the font package has been updated significantly in the meantime.) Not only does `\mathbold{z}` not generate a swashy/bold `z`, but `\bm` no longer works either. :-(

Comment: @Mico Works for me; I redefined the fonts in the `mt2sya` family, which are not involved in this business and declared the bold font to be the available one, then removed the `lite` option. I get the swash.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier on. I also get the swash -- just not the bold-swash. :-(

Comment: @Mico Did you change `{m}` to `{b}`?

Comment: Aah - changing `{m}` to `{b}` did the job! I had somehow overlooked that part earlier this evening...

Answer (score 2):

You could load the `bm` (short for "boldmath", I suppose) package and write `\bm{z}`.

A full MWE and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[zswash]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$z$ $\bm{z}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Writing `{\boldmath$z$}` works too. Not as simple as `$\bm{z}$`, though...